# getting all the property values from property file with property.getProperty("sample.*") in java

Tags: java

**Property.properties**

> sample.user = "sampleUser"
>   sample.age = "sampleAge"
>   sample.location = "sampleLocation"

I can get a property value from a property file by prop.getProperty("sample.user").

I was wondering if below case is possible:

```
prop.getProperty("sample.*");
```

**Result:**
*sampleUser

sampleAge

sampleLocation*

Can anybody please suggest if there is any way to get the above result from the property file?

One solution would be to get whole property file and iterate through it.
 But my property file is very long and I think it would cause
performance issues as I need to call it very often.

Anther would ve use .xml file instead of .properties file.

Comment: *"But my property file is very long and I think it would cause performance issues as I need to call it very often."* And who says that you need to read the file each time? Isn't it quite obvious that you only read the file once and then retrieve the data from the [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) instance?

Comment: The answer is no, and XML is not a solution. You will have to iterate.

Comment: @Tom: so for example, if I want to find sample.*, I would need to iterate through all the entries and then if I want sample2.*, then again I would need to iterate through all entries. Correct?

Comment: @EJP: 
<example>
 <sample user="sampleUser" age="sampleAge" location="sampleLocation"></sample>
</example>
I can directly findElementByTagName and get all the attributes
But as Andrew suggested it will be slower

Comment: Yes, you would have to separately iterate for 'sample2.*', but (a) this is all in-memory, (b) it's likely much quicker than you think, (c) results can be cached. Of course if you have specific use cases and specific performance targets then optimisations can be made, custom data structures introduced etc., but then (always) you have to trade efficiency against complexity / effort.

Comment: @Bhavin If you have two different queries for your data structure, then 'yes', you have to do this twice. But again, you should only read from the file once, because this is the part which costs a lot of time. Not the memory search.

Comment: @Tom & Andrew, good to know.. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Properties` object (a `.properties` file in object form) is just a `Hashtable<Object,Object>` (and a `Map`). Not ideal for any use in 2016, but perfectly workable.

Extracting the matches isn't especially inefficient, and even 000s of lines should return in a trivial amount of time (potentially just a few milliseconds). It all depends how often you need to check. If you only need them once, just cache the resulting `matchingValues` and refer back to it.

No, you can't do `prop.getProperty("sample.*");` directly, but the code is very straightforward via the `Map` interface:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty("sample.user", "sampleUser");
p.setProperty("sample.age", "sampleAge");
p.setProperty("sample.location", "sampleLocation");

Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("sample.*");

final List<String> matchingValues = new ArrayList<>();

for (Entry<Object,Object> each : p.entrySet()) {
    final Matcher m = patt.matcher((String) each.getKey());
    if (m.find()) {
        matchingValues.add((String) each.getValue() );
    }
}

System.out.println(matchingValues);
```

The above matching and building took 0.16 millisecs on my 5-year-old iMac.

Switching to XML representation would be more complicated and definitely slower to load and process.

Comment: I tried accepting it, but it says I don't enough reputation to publicly display the feedback

Answer (score 1):

In **Java 8** it may looks like

```
Properties p = new Properties();
...
List<String> matchingValues = p.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getKey().toString().matches("sample.*"))
                .map(e -> e.getValue().toString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(matchingValues);
```

Comment: Not a criticism, but interestingly this version takes ~ 300-400x as long to execute on my JDK 1.8.0_51 (~65 ms vs 0.17 ms)

Comment: @AndrewRegan sure it's slower because of multiple regexp pattern creation in `filter` predicate. But is it problem if you read property file with e.g. 10 lines?

Comment: Not at all, just interested.

Comment: actually my project is still using Java 6, so I had to go with Andrew Regan's solution. thanks for the solution